# Non-uniform penalty in loss function calculation using Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Is there a simple approach to use have non-uniform penalty while calculating the loss in Keras (or Tensorflow)? 
I mean, assume you have 5000 training samples and they are not of the same importance and we prefer to get more accurate prediction in some cases even at the expense of inaccurate estimation for several other samples. I already have some coefficients for samples representing the importance of them.

Is there any way to implement such models on Keras or Tensorflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a way is to use `sample_weight` in the fit or `fit_generator` function of keras. This will apply the weight per sample. Therefore, the sample_weight vector should have same length as your training set.

Here is sample code:

```
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1000, sample_weight=sample_coefficients)
```

From keras [documentation](https://keras.io/models/model/):

> sample_weight: Optional Numpy array of weights for the training samples, used for weighting the loss function (during training only). You can either pass a flat (1D) Numpy array with the same length as the input samples (1:1 mapping between weights and samples), or in the case of temporal data, you can pass a 2D array with shape (samples, sequence_length), to apply a different weight to every timestep of every sample. In this case you should make sure to specify sample_weight_mode="temporal" in compile().